# Is there anything like hpricot or beautiful soup for php?

Tags: php, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, hpricot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Robust, Mature HTML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php)

I am looking for a good way to parse and modify html documents server side in php. Beautiful soup and hpricot look like very good tools but they are not available for php. Are there any good libraries that can do this in php? Tidy appears to be partially what I am looking for, but it doesn't look like you can use selectors, etc in tidy.

Comment: Think this is basically the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/ . Note that DOMDocument::loadHTML itself is supposed to work on most malformed HTML.