# html parser codeigniter library?

Tags: codeigniter

Does someone here know a html parser library that will work with codeigniter?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to run Simple_html_dom php library on codeigniter

I copied the file **Simple_html_dom.php**  to

```
/system/libraries
```

Then in my controller I call it using

```
require_once('Simple_html_dom.php');
```

To use it I initialized it using this line

```
$html = new Simple_html_dom();
```

Load a page or link using the line

```
$html->load_file('http://www.google.com');
```

and parse or find elements using this line

```
$html->find('table tr td')->plaintext;
```

works fine and fits right to what I needed to do.

Comment: Also, you can probably put it in /application/libraries instead of /system/libraries (I think that's the suggested practice).

Comment: genius, it worked out for me. The only difference is I added the file to /application/libraries. I have also taken the liberty to edit the answer. Thanks to @Matthew

Comment: alright.... gooood! This will be a nice step for adding external library into any version of C.I. @Gerard...

Answer (score 6):

Similar questions have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263800/mechanize-and-beautifulsoup-for-php) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989234/is-there-anything-like-hpricot-or-beautiful-soup-for-php)

Hopefully that helps.

More possibilities include [DOMDocument::loadHTML](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) and [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks a lot @jacolyte but those are native php libraries, I need one that will run with codeigniter's library system

Comment: Most libraries can be used with CodeIgniter (I frequently use `markdown` and others).  Just `require` them from a centra location (like `config/configure.php`), or place them in `libraries/` with a CI-style class wrapper.

Comment: Why do you need one that 'will run with codeigniters library system' ? What difference does it make?

Comment: a php library needs to be extended modified to fit the library structure of codeigniter 

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html